# Função retorno JavaScript

Tags: javascript

```
var pegaNomeMedico = {
    nome : function(){          
        banco.transaction(function(tx){         
            tx.executeSql(sqlMedicos.selecionaTodosOsMedicosSemFiltros, [], function(tx, resposta){
                var linha = resposta.rows.length;
                 return resposta.rows.item(0).nome_medico;              
            })
        })
    }
}

alert(pegaNomeMedico.nome());
```

Ela só esta me retornando undefined

Queria saber o por que ?

Se eu colocar um `alert(resposta.rows.item(0).nome_medico)` funciona normal mais no return não esta vindo o nome do medico

Comment: Parece que essa função é assíncrona. Como está chamando ela? `pegaNomeMedico.nome()`?

Answer (score 1):

Você não pode fazer isso desse jeito. A função banco.transaction provavelmente é assíncrona e remota mais do que o tempo de execução do js para responder.

Faça assim:

```
var pegaNomeMedico = {
    nome : function(callback){          
        banco.transaction(function(tx){         
            tx.executeSql (sqlMedicos.selecionaTodosOsMedicosSemFiltros, [], function(tx, resposta){
                 var resp = resposta.rows.item(0).nome_medico;
                 If (typeof callback == "function")
                     callback(resp);
            })
        })
    }
}

pegaNomeMedico.nome(function(resposta){
    alert(resposta);
});
```

**EDIT**

A pedido do usuário nos comentários:

```
var pegaNomeMedico = {
    nome: null,
    pegaNome: function(){
        return this.nome;
    },
    pegaNomeServidor : function(callback){          
        banco.transaction(function(tx){         
            tx.executeSql (sqlMedicos.selecionaTodosOsMedicosSemFiltros, [], function(tx, resposta){
                 var resp = resposta.rows.item(0).nome_medico;
                 pegaNomeMedico.nome = resp;
                 if (typeof callback == "function")
                     callback(resp);
            })
        })
    }
}
```

Você continua usando a função diretamente assim:

```
pegaNomeMedico.pegaNomeServidor(function(resposta){
    alert(resposta);
});
```

Porém, existe a possibilidade também de executar assim:

```
pegaNomeMedico.pegaNome();
```

Note que, para usar pegaNome() você terá que entender que, se chamada antes do retorno de pegaNomeServidor(), você vai obter como resposta `null`. Isso é incontornável, pois se trata de tempo de execução da query x tempo de execução do JS, que não são simultâneos.

Comment: otimo, mais como faço para chamar o return. tipo assim

Comment: como seria para chamar o return em outro lugar sem ser no alert? Tipo assim pegaNomeMedico.nome();

Comment: É impossível fazer do jeito que você está querendo com uma função do tipo assíncrona. Vou editar a pergunta com outro cenário.

Comment: Nao deu certo não Bruno. continua dando Null